# Call Graphs or Control-Flow-Graph for Objective-C (iOS app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, call-graph, control-flow-graph

Are there any Call-Graph and/or Control-Flow-Graph generators for Objective-C for iOS apps?

Call Graph - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph
Call Graphs gives an inter-procedural view of a program. In a call graph, an edge between two nodes f and g: f --> g
represents the fact that subroutine f calls subroutine g.

Control Flow Graph - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph

Some static tool that let me access the graph using some API/code?
Is there any way to generate call graphs for iOS apps? or even to record the names of all methods invoked by an iPhone application for any user interaction event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you exactly right, but you can print current call stack this way:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for CFG/CG extraction from iOS app packeges you can check [this](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~dbrumley/courses/18487-f13/powerpoint/19-mobile-security.pdf).

Instead, if your starting point is the source code, you might want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082687/can-clang-generate-a-call-graph-for-an-xcode-project-in-objective-c).