# Create a call graph for a file with clang

Tags: clang, graphviz, call-graph

Is there a way to create a call graph with clang that can reasonably fit on a page?

i.e. given:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a;
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

I current get [image]

by using:

```
$ clang++ main.cpp -S -emit-llvm -o - |
opt -analyze -std-link-opts -dot-callgraph
$ cat callgraph.dot | c++filt |
sed 's,>,\\>,g; s,-\\>,->,g; s,<,\\<,g' |
gawk '/external node/{id=$1}$1!=id' | dot -Tpng -ocallgraph.png
```

(which seems like a lot of effort to do something that I would not have expected to be so difficult). I would like to get something that is a bit more reasonable on the horizontal axis. `Unflatten` seems not to have any impact (at least on this file, on other files it seems to have minimal effect).

Is there a way to ensure that the `png` file that is generated can comfortably fit on a page (any standard size)?

**Note:** Code for the above taken from [Generate calling graph for C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373714/generate-calling-graph-for-c-code)

**Update:** Setting page="8.5,11" gives the following:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the first thing to do would be to set the direction of the graph from the default bottom-to-top ranking to left-to-right, by inserting:

```
rankdir=LR;
```

... near the top of the `.dot` file, after the first `{`. That should orient the graph left-to-right and thereby make it much more compact for a case like this that has long node labels. Exactly how this could be done would depend on the format of `callgraph.dot` but, assuming it looks something like this:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=rectangle];
    ...
```

... then something like:

```
sed 's/digraph G {/digraph G { \n rankdir=LR;/'
```

... would do the job.

Another approach that I've taken in the past is to insert dummy nodes into edges to reduce the number of nodes that have the same rank (and would therefore be drawn in the same row (with `rankdir=TB`, which is the default) or column (with `rankdir=LR`). This is straightforward to do when writing `.dot` files by hand but harder to script.

If you wanted to script inserting extra nodes in some edges to spread nodes that would normally be at the same rank over several ranks, you could do this by running `dot -Tplain` to output a plain text file* that includes (among other things) a list of nodes with the X and Y co-ordinates of the center of each node. Then, you could use `gawk` to read that list, find any large group of nodes with the same X co-ordinate (if `rankdir=TB`) or Y co-ordinate (if `rankdir=LR`) and then process the original `.dot` file to insert an extra blank node before (say) half of the nodes in that group so that the group was spread over two ranks rather than one. I haven't had occasion to do this myself, though.

*See Emden Gansner, Eleftherios Koutsofios and Stephen North (2006) [Drawing graphs with dot](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dotguide.pdf), Appendix B.

EDIT: How to automatically insert extra nodes.

Given a `.dot` file `test1.dot` as follows:

```
digraph G {
    n1 -> n20 
    n1 -> n21 
    n1 -> n22 
    n20 -> n3 
    n21 -> n3 
    n22 -> n3
}
```

... which produces the graph shown.

[image]

... running `dot -Tplain test1.dot >test1.plain` gives the file `test1.plain`:

```
graph 1 2.75 2.5
node n1 1.375 2.25 0.75 0.5 n1 solid ellipse black lightgrey
node n20 0.375 1.25 0.75 0.5 n20 solid ellipse black lightgrey
node n21 1.375 1.25 0.75 0.5 n21 solid ellipse black lightgrey
node n22 2.375 1.25 0.75 0.5 n22 solid ellipse black lightgrey
node n3 1.375 0.25 0.75 0.5 n3 solid ellipse black lightgrey
edge n1 n20 4 1.1726 2.0394 1.0313 1.9019 0.83995 1.7159 0.68013 1.5605 solid black
edge n1 n21 4 1.375 1.9958 1.375 1.8886 1.375 1.7599 1.375 1.6405 solid black
edge n1 n22 4 1.5774 2.0394 1.7187 1.9019 1.9101 1.7159 2.0699 1.5605 solid black
edge n20 n3 4 0.57736 1.0394 0.71875 0.90191 0.91005 0.71592 1.0699 0.56054 solid black
edge n21 n3 4 1.375 0.99579 1.375 0.88865 1.375 0.7599 1.375 0.64045 solid black
edge n22 n3 4 2.1726 1.0394 2.0313 0.90191 1.8399 0.71592 1.6801 0.56054 solid black
stop
```

Thus, we can now process the two files together. I'll use Python for this because it is a bit easier to do it in Python than in Awk. For the sake of this example, I've limited the number of nodes in a rank to 2 and I've used the rank as defined by the default bottom-to-top ordering rather than the left-to-right ordering that I've suggested above. I don't know exactly what sort of `.dot` file is being output by `clang`, so there may be a need to modify this example a bit to take that into account.

```
import sys,re;

plain = open(sys.argv[2])
nodesInRank = {}
for line in plain:
    x = line.split()
    rankloc = 3   # rank is in the y column for the vertical case. 
                  # Change this to rankloc = 2 for the horizontal case
    if len(x) > 0 and x[0] == "node":
        nodesInRank[x[rankloc]] = nodesInRank.get(x[rankloc],[]) + [x[1]]

maxNodesInRank = 2
dummies = set()
for n in nodesInRank.values():
    if len(n) > maxNodesInRank:
        dummies = dummies | set(n[:len(n)//2])

dot = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in dot:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line2 = ""
    for d in dummies:
        m = "-> +%s" % (d)
        if re.search(m,line):
            line = re.sub(m,"-> dummy_%s [dir = none]\n dummy_%s -> %s" % (d,d,d),line)
            line2 = '\tdummy_%s [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];' % (d)
    print (line)
    if len(line2) > 0:
        print (line2)
```

Given this Python script, which I've called `breakrank.py`, I can now run it as:

```
python breakrank.py test1.dot test1.plain >test_dummy.dot
```

... which puts the following in `test_dummy.dot`:

```
digraph G {
    n1 -> dummy_n20 [dir = none]
 dummy_n20 -> n20
    dummy_n20 [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];
    n1 -> n21
    n1 -> n22
    n20 -> n3
    n21 -> n3
    n22 -> n3
}
```

If we run this through `dot`, we now get:

[image]

... which gives us what we want, I think.

Comment: The is definitely much better than what I had, but is there a way to randomly split up a rank and make it show up as if it is two levels (without explicitly inserting dummy nodes)

Comment: Would it be possible to get a list of the nodes that are on a rank? I think that if that can be done, the scripting would be easier

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a way to split up a rank without inserting dummy nodes. I've tried weighting edges unevenly but that doesn't adjust the rank of a node as laid out by `dot`, which is (it appears) strictly defined by the topology. If you use some of the other layout packages (e.g. `neato`), using differentially-weighted edges can cluster some nodes and separate others. However, you lose the hierarchical ordering that you get with `dot`.

Comment: If there a way to get dot to output the list of nodes that are in a rank, then the dummy nodes can be scripted no?

Comment: Checking the X and Y co-ordinates of the nodes output in the `-Tplain` format was the most obvious way (for me) to find the node ranks. Another approach would be to analyse the ranking of the nodes using custom graph analysis code, but I think that would be harder to do than the approach I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Inserting the dummy nodes using a script should be fairly straightforward once we know which nodes to insert. If we wanted to insert a dummy node before a node named `n10`, we could do something like `sed 's/-> +n10/-> n10_dummy -> n10/'`, though we'd also have to insert lines in the `.dot` file like `n10_dummy [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];` to make the node `n10_dummy` invisible.

Comment: I think the insertion of the `n10_dummy [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];` is easy, but I have no idea how to find out what nodes should be connected

Comment: I've amended my answer to automatically generate dummy nodes where there are many nodes with the same rank.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explaining the two parameters? Is one the original `.dot` file the other the plain version of the same file?

Comment: Glad to help. I've edited my answer to make it clear that the first parameter to the Python script is the original `.dot` file and the second parameter is the output from `dot -Tplain test1.dot`.

Comment: It works great for the vertical layout, but is there a way to make it work with the horizontal as well?

Comment: I've amended the Python script in my answer to cover this point.

Comment: Thanks! Recording a slightly more general sed invocation for my own reference, `sed -i '0,/{/s//{\nrankdir=LR;/' *.dot`