# Trying to visualize an abstract syntax tree in graphviz dot, and it's just way too wide. How to fix?

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, graphviz

So I'm working on a language and I wanted to, mostly out of curiosity, see if I could visualize the abstract syntax tree of a file. After some looking around I found graphviz dot, converted my AST prettyprinter to be able to output to this kind of format:

```
digraph G {
    main -> parse -> execute;
    main -> init;
    main -> cleanup;
    execute -> make_string;
    execute -> printf
    init -> make_string;
    main -> printf;
    execute -> compare;
}
```

But my problem is, when I run

```
dot -Tpng dotf.gv -o graph.png
```

On the input file, I end up with a file that is 8000 pixels in width, which is just not practical. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhlyY.png).

I don't know if it's possible to fix, but if someone can I'd be grateful.

Comment: I'm not a grapahviz expert but [aspect](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:aspect) might help.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do would be to set the direction of the graph from the default bottom-to-top ranking to left-to-right, by inserting:

```
rankdir=LR;
```

... in the .dot file. That should orient the graph left-to-right and thereby make it much more compact for a case like this that probably has many nodes with long node labels.

There are some other ideas for reducing the width of graphs like this in [Create a call graph for a file with clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458738/create-a-call-graph-for-a-file-with-clang/16225953#16225953).