# Search C++ call graph recursively for specific functions

Tags: c++, c, clang, code-analysis, call-graph

I have a large C/C++ project where I would like to analyse the call graph for a subset of functions.

Ex for something like:

```
void A_Func1(){}
void A_Func2(){}

void IntermediateFunc()
{
  A_Func1();
  A_Func2();
}

void StartFunc()
{
  IntermediateFunc();
}
```

I would like to get the list of functions that starts with "A_" called directly or indirectly from StartFunc.

My first thought was using clang which has the CallGraph action, but the documentation is sparse and I am slowly getting to the conclusion that I cannot use it how I want.

So the question:
How do I use clangs tooling libraries to perform generate such a list?

Comment: Hmm asking questions is tricky. Apparently aksing for a tool to solve the above problem is ok, asking how to do it with clang is also ok. Just not asking both at the same time. That is off-topic.

Comment: Updated to be a concrete clang question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer from *polkovnikov.ph* to be the cleaner method of doing this. I wasn't aware that the `.dot` is so simple, and I will definitely use that way for similar problems.

Unfortunately I also have to analyse software components where the interface to other components are *C* functions - which are used through the `extern` keyword. They do not show up in the *clang* call graph because of an internal filter (`includeInGraph (const Decl *D)`) in [clang::CallGraph](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CallGraph.html).

So I had to copy `clang::CallGraph`, remove the limitation and use it in an `clang::ASTConsumer` like:

```
virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext &Context) {
    _visitor.TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
    for (auto root : _visitor)
    {
        if (const clang::NamedDecl* namedDecl = llvm::dyn_cast_or_null<clang::NamedDecl>(root.first))
            if(namedDecl->getIdentifier() != nullptr && namedDecl->getIdentifier()->getName().startswith("Start"))
            {
                llvm::outs() << "StartFunc: " << namedDecl->getName() << "\n";
                printAFunctions(root.second);
            }
    }
}
void printAFunctions(const clang::CallGraphNode* node)
{
    if (node != nullptr)
    {
        if (const clang::NamedDecl* namedDecl = llvm::dyn_cast_or_null<clang::NamedDecl>(node->getDecl()))
        {
            if (namedDecl->getName().startswith("A_"))
            {
                llvm::outs() << "A_ call: " << namedDecl->getName() << "\n";
            }
        }
        for (auto subNode : *node)
        {
            printAFunctions(subNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stumbled on why didn't you accept your own answer until I've finally remembered there's a 48 hours cooldown on this spell :) Anyway, you've made a great example on LLVM API.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: Thanks. It is a shame it didn't work with the .dot file. But since I had to adapt clang internals anyway, the second best way was to create my own AST visitor based on the clang::CallGraph.

Answer (score 3):

[Clang outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458738/create-a-call-graph-for-a-file-with-clang) `.dot` file for it's callgraph. It's quite a [simple format](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) that can be easily parsed with a tool like [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online). When you get the call [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), you can run a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), that marks all the nodes with `A_` prefix on it.

The other solution is to use Clang's codebase to [do it yourself](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CallGraph.html). As you could already find out, it's quite an involved approach.

Also, you should be aware that clang generates an optimistic call graph, i.e. "what functions could be called". For example, `void f() { if (g()) h(); }` "calls" both `g` and `h`, even if `bool g() { return false; }`.

Possibly, you're looking for "all functions that are really called from there". Then you need to run [some profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows) to gather the call stacks.

The best solution would be to make a [debugger script](http://scn.sap.com/people/stephen.pfeiffer/blog/2010/12/14/abap-debugger-scripting-basics) for some IDE, but I'm not aware of any IDE for C++ that have such option.