# Invert Caller Tree in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In the Instruments app, an invert call tree can be inspected in various profiling modules. Is it possible to view such a call tree to a particular selector? I know there are callee and caller in Assistant Editor now, but is there a plugin that generates such a tree? Or did I missed some features in Xcode?

Comment: I assume you could do this yourself with `dtrace` although I am not familiar enough to give an example. http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hooked-on-dtrace-part-1/ and http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/ might be a decent intro.

Comment: So far as I know, `dtrace` provides runtime profiling, not static analysis. My wish is simple, perform project-wide search recursively, until every branch hit something like `-viewDidLoad` or `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, of course notification, blocks and many other corner cases should be handled in order to get a neat result.

Comment: I think what your looking for is an llvm call graph see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373714/generate-calling-graph-for-c-code

Comment: I didn't know you were after static analysis; the question referenced by @GayleDDS seems to be the best approach