# c++ test to check if a function is implemented recursively

Tags: c++, testing, recursion

for automated grading of assignments I'm trying to develop a test that checks whether a c++ function is implemented recursively.

My current ideas are:
1) parse the function code and check for the keywords {for, while, goto}
2) somehow monitor the call stack. Maybe from a different thread, or by scripting GDB.

I'm curious about other ideas or maybe somebody has already implemented one of the above.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Monitoring the call stack will only serve your purpose if you do it for unoptimized binaries. An optimizing compiler might transform a recursion into a loop. Walking the AST with clang might work, but could still easily be fooled (`if (false) recurse();`).

Comment: I think parsing for keywords (not in the function but in the whole program, or someone might `#define gotcha while` outside) would be the best option.

Comment: Can you introduce policies like "all function calls must use an external wrapper provided by me"? It would require to know in advance the prototype of all student-written functions. But it could open the way of using call-counters. It would however be not too hard to work around this, if students intetionally try to or fail/forget/misunderstand wrapper-calling.

Comment: Alernative policy "all functions have to call `enter(id)` at start and `leave(id)` at end. This would get around the need to know all prototypes in advance, reducing it to providing unique IDs for each function.

Comment: @Yunnosch `#define repeat(x) x x x` and then `repeat(enter(id);) repeat(leave(id);)`. It's more security by obfuscation...

Comment: @MaxLanghof I do not believe in security by obfuscation. But please elaborate your contribution. I did not yet get the point.

Comment: @MaxLanghof So it was an indirect way of agreeing with my "not too hard to work around"?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah. Didn't know how to word it better, sorry.

Comment: How about setting up the problem in such a way that it guarantees a stack overflow if solved with recursion?

Comment: let's say you scan the code of a function "foo" for a supposedly call to itself. How would you check if it's actually calling itself or an overloaded version of "foo"

Comment: @Matzi How would you check the correctness of a program that overflows the stack?

Comment: @byxor You can test the correctness with a smaller input, and test if it uses recursion with a larger input. It is an automated test system, I assume it is able to run the same code multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Clang's [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) to parse the C++ code. Then walk through the AST and build a call graph (i.e. graph with functions as nodes and edges as calls from one function to another). Search that graph for cycles, using [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm). If a cycle exists, you have a potentially recursive implementation.

If the code uses dynamic dispatch (i.e. virtual functions), [this paper](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse501/04wi/papers/bacon-oopsla96.pdf) may help you. If the code uses function pointers, [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2450140) might but in general, the problem is undecidable.

If you're only looking for *direct* recursion, scanning the function's body AST for calls to itself is enough, but theoretically you'd still need to check dynamic dispatch and function pointers.

Edit: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373714/347964) for generating a callgraph.