# How to demangle a function name generated by opt with LLVM's c++filt and how to omit some intermediate nodes?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, call-graph

I am reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373814/16941344) to generate a well-look call graph with clang++-13 and opt-13

```
❯ clang++-13 --version
Homebrew clang version 13.0.1
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
❯ opt-13 --version
Homebrew LLVM version 13.0.1
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
  Host CPU: westmere
```

Here is an example code:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct A { 
  A(int);
  void f(); // not defined, prevents inlining it!
};

int main() {
  std::vector<A> v;
  v.push_back(42);
  v[0].f();
}
```

Here is the command I am using:

```bash
clang++-13 -S -emit-llvm main1.cpp -o - |
   opt-13 -analyze -std-link-opts -dot-callgraph -enable-new-pm=0
```

Here comes a message but I don't understand it:

```
Writing '<stdin>.callgraph.dot'...
Printing analysis 'Print call graph to 'dot' file':
Pass::print not implemented for pass: 'Print call graph to 'dot' file'!
```

Since the dot file is still generated, I ran the following command:

```bash
cat \<stdin\>.callgraph.dot |
   c++filt |
   sed 's,>,\\>,g; s,-\\>,->,g; s,<,\\<,g' |
   gawk '/external node/{id=$1} $1 != id' |
   dot -Tpng -ocallgraph.png
```

And this is the result:

[image: The output of my platform]

This is far way out what I expected:

[image: What I expected]

I don't see any difference between the answer and mine, however the output is different. I understand what shown in my output are [decorated function names](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355466/why-are-function-names-decorated-in-c), yet read and understand them is tormenting.

I wonder if there are ways to improve my output, or read and understand the output more efficiently?

---

### Update

I have outlined the progress in my answer below. However, the question is not fully answered:

1. Is there a way to parse decorated function names on MacOS?
2. The generated graph is still huge, but we can wish it gets smaller, by omitting some too-detailed nodes. But, how?

Answer (score 0):

The function name demangling problem is with LLVM's `c++filt`. Here is a small demonstration:

You can generate a dot file with `clang` and `opt` either on MacOS or Linux. The specific instructions may vary due to the version of your `clang` and `opt`, but generally they are the same. I used `clang++-13` and `opt-13` in my original question, and here I use `clang++-14` and `opt-14`

```bash
clang++-14 -S -emit-llvm main1.cpp -o - |
   opt-14 -analyze -dot-callgraph -enable-new-pm=0
```

The decorated function names are like:

```
_ZNSt3__14pairINS_16reverse_iteratorIP1AEES4_EC2B6v15006IS4_S4_LPv0EEEOT_OT0_
```

If we use LLVM's `c++filt`, it can not parse it:

```bash
❯ c++filt --version
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++filt
Apple LLVM version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  Optimized build.
  Default target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
  Host CPU: apple-m1
❯ c++filt _ZNSt3__14pairINS_16reverse_iteratorIP1AEES4_EC2B6v15006IS4_S4_LPv0EEEOT_OT0_
_ZNSt3__14pairINS_16reverse_iteratorIP1AEES4_EC2B6v15006IS4_S4_LPv0EEEOT_OT0_
```

However, if we use GNU's `c++filt`:

```bash
➜  ~ c++filt --version
GNU c++filt (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
➜  ~ c++filt _ZNSt3__14pairINS_16reverse_iteratorIP1AEES4_EC2B6v15006IS4_S4_LPv0EEEOT_OT0_
std::__1::reverse_iterator<A*>&& std::__1::pair<std::__1::reverse_iterator<A*>, std::__1::reverse_iterator<A*> >::pair[abi:v15006]<std::__1::reverse_iterator<A*>, std::__1::reverse_iterator<A*>, (void*)0>(std::__1::reverse_iterator<A*>&&)
```

Things just work fine